# how to connect with mysql web based database server using dynamic IP's

Tags: java, mysql, linux, dynamic, webserver

i have a linux server that i am used to host websites (mysql installed and working properly on this server)

now what im trying to do is develop a java POS system 
i need to use mysql as database engine and planning to use my linux web server as a database server

problem is i cant use static ip for client pc's but in order to access mysql instance i have to allow client ip address first

I found these solutions on web :

1. Use wildcard % and allow all the IP addresses in the world - i think this as a bad idea
2. Also we can find clients ISP's IP range and allow that range - this is ok but some of ISP's in my county refused to provide their IP range and i think their should be better way than this

Question : 
**I'm just wondering what methods are used in the software  industry to implement web based systems 
and i need secure,reliable solution for this**

Comment: Build an API rather than exposing the raw SQL service to the world.

Comment: what are the technologies  that i can use to build API ? (i mean programming languages )

Comment: @nicoleino Any programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make it in php or java or in python  it will not affect your client app, your client app will just send http request with authentication details 
like http://host.com/?username=me&password=sec&action=getUserList

And your host server will return a response in JSON or XML format as per his request
Like:

```
<user>
<name>vivek</name>
<email>email@email.com</eail>
</user>
```

then your client app will parse this response and can use that.
, or google about Restful APIs you will see lots of tutorials on all technologies,  Or use this service apiary.io

Comment: thanks for your reply .  I'm just wondering what methods are used in the software industry ? do you think this as industrial solution

Comment: Yes, you can see that on indeed.com apis , currently RESTFUL api is the solution, android app ios app receives data from server through restfull api, you can create restful apis using php or java or using python

Comment: based on your example will it add clients ip address to the white list or will it return accessible URL?

Comment: there is nothing related to IP, you will authorize client by providing authentication on each request (or dont use any authorization) .(URL) then host have to   return the string as response. for example https://indeed-indeed.p.mashape.com/apisearch , it is returning JSON response that you havnt provided authentication key, so by this way your client app and talk to your server host.

Answer (score 1):

Given the restrictions you have in your situation, you'll need to go with solution 1.  Just ensure that you have strong passwords.